# s3_out: unable to sign request without credentials set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-proxy, fluentd, fluent-docker

I try to use "instance_profile_credentials" at ec2 instance as credentials. However I get

`2021-09-16 14:16:50 +0000 [error]: #0 unexpected error error_class=RuntimeError error="can't call S3 API. Please check your credentials or s3_region configuration. error = #<Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: unable to sign request without credentials set>"`

I pretty sure my s3_region is correct, and I can use cli "aws s3 cp  " to copy object at command line, not sure what going wrong.

I wonder if that because I am under a http proxy. However, I already setup "proxy_uri" parameter. Not sure what else I can do to check what going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the code that produces the error?

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I am just trying to use https://docs.fluentd.org/output/s3, and I've update the config to


`
  @type s3
  <instance_profile_credentials>
  </instance_profile_credentials>

  s3_bucket <bucket>
  s3_region <region>
  proxy_uri http://proxyhost.com:port
 `